# How to know which points pcl::PassThrough and pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval removes?

Tags: pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to know which point is removed/filtered out from an input cloud after applying pcl::PassThrough and pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval filters. What I mean by "which point" is the x and y index values of a 3D Point in the sensor plane, or simply the index value of the point.

I have checked pcl::ExtractIndices and [pcl_base.h](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/pcl/html/pcl__base_8h_source.html#l00062) and many other source files, but I couldn't find an easy way to do that.

Thanks...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9158/how-to-know-which-points-pcl::passthrough-and-pcl::statisticaloutlierremoval-removes?/) by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 288 on 2011-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2014-05-09**:
You can get x,y,z of points that you want when you call pcl::PassThrough and pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval filters. What I don't know is how to know the indices of original point cloud. Anyone know? Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Corey,

I think you misunderstood the actual problem here.

It is not possible to know which points are removed/filtered out in the current version of PCL for the filters that I have mentioned above. This feature/addon is going to be included in the upcoming versions of PCL, probably 2.0.

---

Originally posted by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) with karma: 288 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The statistical outlier removal object has a setNegative() method which will extract outliers instead of inliers. Simply pass this method 'true'.

For the passthrough filter, you can use setFilterLimitsNegative(). Pass this method 'true' as well to get the outliers.

---

Originally posted by [Corey Montella](https://answers.ros.org/users/45/corey-montella/) with karma: 63 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2